# No posix acl in debian Wheezy with ext4

Tags: debian, filesystems, ext4, debian-wheezy

I was running a new script and encountered the following error:

> Your filesystem or build does not support posix ACLs

So I thought no problem, just add  acl,user_xattr to my fstab. It now looks like the following:

> UUID=01f6d86f-7840-49af-a4e9-191d6e2aeddc /               ext4 relatime,acl,user_xattr,errors=remount-ro 0       1

Did a restart and did a mount to check if everything was ok but it wasn't instead it showed the following:

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/01f6d86f-7840-49af-a4e9-191d6e2aeddc on / type ext4   (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)

So no acl. Did it manually with

> mount / -o remount,acl

But that didnt help. So I'm stuck at the moment. I'm running Debian Wheezy RC1 with an ext4 fs. libacl and libacl-dev are installed.

Comment: Are you using a custom kernel without ACL support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ext4` has the `acl` and `user_xattrs` options enabled *by default*¹.  You would have to use `noacl` or `nouser_xattr` to *not* use them.

① http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/102405/

Answer (score 0):

On my Fedora 18 system the filesystems show as:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_machine-LogVol04 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
```

(no `acl` mentioned) but ACLs do  work. I do `getfacl xxx` and `setfacl -m ... xxx` without trouble.

What are the exact commands in the script that fail?

Perhaps you should take the issue up with Debian's bugzilla...